# Convert column object into integer in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset:

```
training.head()
Out[115]: 
GridID        date      Shift  Accident  
0       1  2010-10-08      Night         0                
1       1  2011-02-16    Morning         0                     
2       1  2014-05-31      Night         0                   
3       1  2011-04-03  Afternoon         0                   
4       1  2013-02-20    Morning         0
```

I would like to replace in column Shift the words "Morning", "Afternoon" and "Night" with integers 1, 2 and 3, repectively.

I tried:

```
training['Shift'].str.replace('Morninig','1').astype(int)
```

But it gives me:

```
 ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Night'
```

Comment: first replace all text and later change column to `int` using `astype(int)`

Comment: I tried to replace all texts but it gives me the error as shown above

Comment: it seams you didn't change all text - you still have some `Night` in column. Column can have only one `type` so `astype(int)` convert all elements in column.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) instead of `str.replace`, and pass it a dictionary from old value to new value. Also make sure you use `inplace=True` or reassign it to the series.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['morning', 'afternoon']})

print(df)

>>            a
   0    morning
   1  afternoon

df['a'].replace({'morning': 1,
                 'afternoon': 2}, inplace=True)

print(df)

>>    a
   0  1
   1  2

print(df['a'].dtype)

>> int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df2=pd.Series(data={'Night':3, 'Morning':1, 'Afternoon':2})
df.Shift = df.Shift.map(df2)
```

---

```
df2 = pd.read_clipboard()
df3=pd.Series(data={'Night':3, 'Morning':1, 'Afternoon':2})
df2.Shift = df2.Shift.map(df3)
df2
```

Output:

[image]